# Java NIO Paths: getting the base path from a full path?

Tags: java, path, nio

With [Java NIO Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) objects:

- If I have a base path `b` and a relative path `r`, to get the full path `f` I can call `b.resolve(r)`.
- If I have the full path `f` and the base path `b`, to get the relative path `r` I can call `b.relativize(f)`.
- But what can I do if I have `f` and `r`, and want to find `b`?

Looking over the `Path` API, I can't see any simple/straightforward solution.  The best I've been able to come up with is to simultaneously iterate over `getParent()` for both `f` and `r` until `r'` is empty/null, then `f'` should be `b`.  But that seems clunky and inefficient.

I also tried a solution based on `f.subpath()` but that method strips the root component (e.g. `C:\`).

Comment: Did you see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#endsWith-java.nio.file.Path-

Comment: @TheGuest `endsWith()` can tell me if `r` is really relative to `f` or not, which is useful, but I need to go the next step and actually derive `b`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To retrieve the base path, you can use `subpath()` by passing  as begin index  `0`and as end index the difference of path elements between the full path and the relative path, that is `fullPath.getNameCount() - relativePath.getNameCount()`

For example :

```
Path fullPath = Paths.get("C:/folder1/folder2/a/b/c.txt");
Path relativePath = Paths.get("b/c.txt");
Path basePath =  fullPath.getRoot().resolve(fullPath.subpath(0, fullPath.getNameCount() - relativePath.getNameCount()));
System.out.println("basePath=" + basePath);
```

output :

> basePath=C:\folder1\folder2\a

Note that `fullPath.getRoot().resolve()` is required because Windows doesn't consider a token with `:` as a path element in its `subpath()` implementation.
So in the actual example, `C:\` will never be returned by `subpath()`.
 `C:\` is considered in the Windows implementation as the `root` component.

As a general note, even if our application run on an Unix based OS, we should keep it to be not OS dependent. The OS where the JVM runs may be different in the future.

Comment: This is one of the solutions I considered, but as I mentioned in the question, it strips the root component from the path.  For example, if `fullPath` was `C:\folder1\...` (on Windows), `basePath` would still end up as `folder1\...`.  I need `basePath` to be `C:\folder1\...`

Comment: I suppose I could do something like `fullPath.getRoot().resolve(basePath);` to restore the root component.  It's not as elegant as I would like but maybe that's as good as it gets...

Comment: Indeed, for windows paths yo  may have the drive stripped. It is caused by the `:` character. It's not very elegant indeed but you don't have many choices as the nio api doesn't provide a method to find the base path between a full and a relative path.